# Shell script overwrite exception

Tags: bash, shell

I've got two directories for my website on a server (Debian) - production and development. As I'm ready on some development stage I want to move new data to production site. The easiest way (as I think) is to write a shell script. But there are several config files, I don't want to overwrite. All canfig files have *config* word in their names. So I need to overwrite all files in all directories except files that have *config* in names.

Is that possible?

Comment: You could use `rsync` with an `exclude`. Try it out on some dummy files somewhere - not on your production system! `rsync -av --exclude '*config*' source/ destination/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for filename in $(ls Directory | grep -v config); do
  # something with $filename
done
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the right way. But. It skipps config.core.php file in root directory, but still copies config.inc.php files in subdirectories... i use cp -r $filename ../test to copy files